# leer variables de un txt en php

Tags: php

Hola quiero hacer lo siguiente, voy a generar plantillas de configuración de equipos y el usuario define previamente ciertos valores que son claves para la generación de esa plantilla, entonces mi idea para que mi archivo php no sea gigante es que ponga la plantilla en un txt y la lea desde php reemplazando las variables que ya definio el usuario, sería algo así:

el php tiene lo siguiente (las variables las toma de un formulario, pero lo pongo así para hacerlo más simple):

```
<?php 
$valor1= "azul";
$valor2= "rojo";
$valor3= "verde";
$plantilla=fopen("fortinet.txt","r") or die("error al leer archivo");

while(!feof($plantilla))
{
    $plantillaFinal = fgets($plantilla);
    $plantillaFinal = nl2br($plantillaFinal);
    echo $plantillaFinal;
}

?>
```

el txt tiene el siguiente contenido:

```
edit 1
set name $valor1
set color $valor2
set policy $valor3
set bandwidth $valor4
end
```

el tema es que cuando se muestra el contenido del txt no se reemplaza la variable. espero me puedan ayudar, saludos!

Comment: Hola, no sé si ese archivo `.txt` se modifique con las variables, pero a simple vista veo que solo tienes el `fopen` en modo lectura, intenta con `$plantilla=fopen("fortinet.txt","r+") or die("error al leer archivo");` ya que `r+` te permite leer y escribir

Comment: @Joseph Entiendo que la plantilla no deba ser modificada. En tal caso se volcaría a un nuevo fichero... :)

Comment: en qué parte del código guardas? dentro del while solo veo `fgets()` y `nl2br()`

Comment: @DavidJP gracias, ya entiendo con tu respuesta.

Comment: @Joseph No, no guardo. Simplemente muestro por pantalla, como ha hecho el OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba así:

```
<?php 

$valor=[
    '1'=>"azul",
    '2'=>"rojo",
    '3'=>"verde",
];
$plantilla=fopen("fortinet.txt","r") or die("error al leer archivo");

$txt=null;

while(!feof($plantilla))
{
    $plantillaFinal = fgets($plantilla);
    $plantillaFinal = nl2br($plantillaFinal);
    $txt.=$plantillaFinal;
}

foreach($valor as $i=>$dato)
    $txt=str_replace('$valor'.$i,$dato,$txt);

echo $txt;
```

Para obtener:

```
edit 1
set name azul
set color rojo
set policy verde
set bandwidth $valor4
end
```

Espero que te ayude. Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios para completar la respuesta.

Comment: Entonces, utiliza una array asociativo, en vez de uno enumerado. Así podrás terminar cada variable `$valor` como prefieras. El código continuaría funcionando. El orden en el que aparezcan en el fichero es irrelevante funcionará en cualquier caso. Prueba y verás :)

Comment: woow, eso no me lo sabía muchas gracias master